Length of Path is bigger than 8192 bytes while installing Intellij
I am getting below error while installing Intellij.
Length of Path is bigger than 8192 bytes

I am using windows 8 operating system. It does not contain any properties like LongPathsEnabled in registry.

Maybe THIS might help

Intellij minimum requirements for 2024.1 are Microsoft Windows 10 1809 64-bit or later. It might work but most software have stopped supporting Windows 8 by now.

Well what's the value of PATH and why is there so much stuff in it?

run cmd , in cmd, run echo %PATH% > DDD.txt , next command notepad DDD.txt , check content , PATH environment to bigger.

aled is correct here: since Windows 8 support was dropped in January 2023, so the latest IntelliJ IDEA version doesn't support Windows 8, too. You can either consider updating OS to Windows 10 or installing the older IDE version, for example, 2022.2 or so.
